Editing a question which has been edited by a moderator and then locked
I have posted the following question on the law exchange: For copyright determination purposes, how can AI-generated content (eg.lyrics) be proven as such rather than human generated?
This has received some good answers providing specific information, as well as some poor/non-answers and comments which are either completely generic (i.e fail to address the specifics of the question at all), or ignore the difference between the IT and legal side of the question (some comments and one 'answer' from a particular moderator qualifies as shit-posting in my view).
I do not wish to delete the question if possible. I wish to edit the question to ensure it receives answers which are as specific and useful as possible, further clarify the distinction between the legal side and IT side of the question, and discourage further entirely generic answers of the kind mentioned (presumably this is what set the moderator off), as well as make a couple of grammar/punctuation corrections before offering a bounty. Unfortunately said moderator has also undone my recent edits to convey the above, and has also locked the question (no reason given thus far).
I wish that the edited question read as follows (the edited part is the final paragraph beginning 'Please note'):
Title:

For copyright determination purposes, how can AI-generated content
(eg.lyrics) be proven as such rather than human-generated?

Question:

Most answers I have seen to the question of whether AI-generated
content is copyrightable cite law in the US and other countries
limiting copyright to human-created content. However all the answers I
have seen fail to address the question of how a government copyright
office and then potentially later a rights holder, copyright
enforcement company, or court would be able to prove it was
AI-generated.
AI platforms are often vague about retention and/or use of user input
and AI output, and it is not clear to me how accessible this data
would be to government copyright offices, courts, and copyright
enforcement companies for purposes of determining whether a particular
lyric were AI generated.
In some cases, already copyrighted content may appear verbatim in AI
output, and to the extent this can be easy recognized as an existing
work this would make the AI authorship question moot. However most of
the time this will not be the case, especially where AI only enhances
a user's original work rather than composing something from scratch or
with minimal prompts.
Please note, generic information about how things are proven in legal
cases does not answer this question. The question is directed at the
legal specifics of how these particular types of case would proceed or
have proceeded in the past, i.e what types of evidence might be sought
(eg. AI tool conversations/output), how accessible those types of
evidence might be to the court, identification of methods a court may
use (eg. stylistic analysis of content), burden of proof in such
cases, etc. The technical/IT side of the question is addressed at the
following question, also on stack exchange: For copyright purposes,
how can AI-generated content (eg.lyrics) be proven as such rather than
human-generated?

What can I do to have to the above edit made to the question and, if possible, have this particular moderator prevented from further editing/locking the question?
Note: It has been pointed by others out that the same question (title) was simultaneously posted on the AI.SE site.  This was intentional, has nothing to do with the difference in the quality of answers, and I am aware of no rule which prohibits doing this. The two questions are different in the context of these two sites. One is about the legal side of the issue, the other is IT technicalities side of the question. If this wasn't clear from the site context, it is abundantly clear from the edits (partly the reason for them, and another reason their removal is bad practice from the moderator).

The question is asked and answered; don’t edit it.
If you want to ask a different question, ask a different question.

Edits to the question are never allowed to even attempt to invalidate answers
Read the following and realize: you violated a policy that is one of the core fundamentals of the Stack Exchange Network in general. You can not and under no circumstances do an edit to the question that invalidates an answer. You tried that. It's disrespectful and got you not just a comment that told you that it is not allowed, but also a content dispute smack on that question.
Is there a policy on editing questions to clarify them after answers have already there been posted?
Change to question invalidates my answer, what to do?

In general, that's not allowed - the OP of the question should not change his/her question in a way that invalidates existing answers. You can rollback the edit (if you have >2k reputation), or suggest an edit based on an earlier revision. Indicate in the edit summary that you rolled back because the scope of the question has changed and invalidated your answer.

How to deal with questions that change

It is not the down votes that are stupid; the question being changed is the problem.
In such a case, one thing should happen: the question needs to be reverted, if it was truly altered significantly.
If you can't or don't want to do it, or if you already have and the OP edits it back, flag the question as "Other" and describe the problem. We'll take care of it.


Other than your control over the acceptance checkmark, you can't dictate what content would answer the question. If you're turning to us for our view of the law, you need to leave it open for us to present our view of the law. I believe this is what this comment is implying to you. You can't ask a question, get answers to that, and then essentially say, "I didn't want those answers."
Your proposed "clarification" would say:

Please note, generic information about how things are proven in legal cases does not answer this question

But in fact, several users believe that such an answer would answer the question. I am one of them.
You then would say:

The question is directed at the legal specifics...

However, it is not. Your question is directed at technical specifics and legal generalities. To the extent that your question is legal it is answerable as a general question about evidence. Even though you might think you're asking about something legally specific, those with expertise, who you have turned to, see it otherwise.

I have at no point asked for any answers to be removed. The non-answers have been duly flagged as such and I leave it with the other moderators from there. I have removed the word tampering from the question in case this is misinterpreted as a request to have the mod's answers removed.

please see the title of this post: 'Editing a question which has been edited by an abusive moderator and then locked'. Are you able to answer this question?

The question is also clearly directed at legal specifics,not legal generalities,as mentioned multiple times.
